# dragover mouse event contain file info in XUL application using javascript

Tags: javascript, xul, xulrunner

I'm writing a XUL application using JavaScript for the coding. I would like to be able to drag files onto a control in this application and, when dropped, have them show up.

This seems like it would be almost exactly like the tutorial [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/Dragging_and_Dropping_Multiple_Items), but when I break in the drag and drop event handlers in a debugger, the dataTransfer member of the event isn't there!

How should I be doing this?

Thanks,
Nathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These [features](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/Drag_and_Drop) were added in [Firefox 3.1](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/all-beta.html), and [XULRunner 1.9.1](http://starkravingfinkle.org/blog/2009/01/unofficial-xulrunner-191-builds/), so make sure you are using the correct version. Be aware these builds are still in beta.

The old API for drag and drop is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drag_and_Drop).